# How to iterate a function n times until a certain outcome?

Tags: python

I need to iterate a function until a certain outcome is reached. There are actually three different outcomes that will need to stop the loop from running. However, I need the function to iterate over the naturals, so basically I don't want to limit my range. How would I go about doing this? I assume I need to make a for loop or a while loop of some sort, but I have limited Python experience. Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use [`range()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range)

Comment: Can you sketch out (in pseudocode) roughly what you mean?

Comment: Its too hard to answer broad questions like this. Add some code to make it concrete and we will give it a look.

Comment: I think I need to think about my question a little more. I started typing some code to show you guys, but I realized I hadn't thought long enough about it. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the `itertools` module. [Documentation here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

`itertools.count()` will give you the naturals and will never run out. `itertools.takewhile()` will continue to consume a sequence until some specified function returns `True`.

Comment: Thank you! I think I need to think about my problem a little longer, but this will help a lot.

Answer (score 0):

```
index = 0
while True:
    if end_conditions:
        break
    index += 1
```

A for loop is usually used to loop through items in an `iterable`, which tend to be bounded. This `while True` method indicates that the loop could theoretically loop forever. You can use an if statement to break the loop when you satisfy the conditions.